# How would the place one spent most time growing there be called?

Tags: word-request

There is [place of birth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Place_of_birth), but it's only for birth. What would we call the place that one spent most of their childhood until they are being an adult? "Place of growth"? Also, what about the place that one is currently living? "Place of living"?

Comment: "The place where I grew up" is natural. "Place of growth" is not.

Comment: There a colloquial expression "my old stomping grounds", meaning a very familiar place, somewhere you spent a lot of time at some point. Someone who's lived a lot of places might refer to more than one place this way, but only places where they'd lived for a long time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would call the place where someone grew up their **hometown**

> hometown ([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hometown))
> the city or town where one was born or grew up

I would call the place where someone currently resides their **residence** or **place of residence**

> residence (Google/Lexico)
> a person's home; the place where someone lives.

Comment: Hometown works in most cases.  If someone has lived in city A for 40 years and then moves to city B, city A would most likely be considered their home town.  **The town/city/place where I grew up,** probably works a little better.

Answer (score 6):

The usual expression, at least in British English, is "I was born in X but brought up in Y".

Comment: Or “…raised in Y.”

Comment: @gidds as KateBunting says, BrE is "brought up". "raised" is AmE.

Answer (score 4):

I would refer to the place where I grew up as "my childhood home", and the place I currently live at as "my current home".

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a native speaker, so I don't know how common the word is in English, but Heimat seems like a good fit?

It's a word that refers to a place one has an emotional and cultural connection with due to having grown up there. How big that "place" is, is undefined. It can be a street, but it can also be an entire country. It depends on the context. A British expat in India would call the UK as his Heimat, but a Londoner who moved to Liverpool would refer to London when mentioning his Heimat.

Comment: I am a native speaker. I haven't heard heimat used in the UK before and I assume that it's a loanword from German. When I google 'heimat' it automatically triggers google translate and suggests the translation 'homeland.' The word homeland is like hometown but you'd use it for a larger region such as a country. I don't know if there's any nuance lost when you translate heimat to homeland/hometown.

Comment: I'm a 28-year-old American and I don't think I've ever seen or heard the word "heimat" before. If I had seen it today without an explanation of what it means, I would have guessed that it means something related to "home," but I would have no idea what the specific meaning is.

Comment: Heimat appears to be a German word, gaining some currency among English speakers, in some circles. Expect to need to define it every time you use it.

Comment: In the UK there was a television series called Heimat (in the original _Heimat eine Chronik in elf Teilen_) but that would be the sum total of the knowledge of the word amongst English speakers here except the small number who studied German at school.

Comment: @AnonFNV (and others): I wasn't sure if it being a word in English. Wikipedia said it was, so I suggested it.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heimat

Comment: It seems to me that that Wikipedia makes it clear that "Heimat" is not an English word. The article says at the very beginning that it is a German word, and throughout the article, the word always appears in quotation marks or in italics, indicating that it is a foreign word, not an English word.

Comment: @TannerSwett It also says that on the page for my language, even though it is very commonly used. So I don't think that's a reliable metric. 
Also: why would the English wiki have pages for words that don't exist in that language?

Comment: Wikipedia has an article about pretty much every topic that is considered notable, and the German word "Heimat" is considered notable, and so Wikipedia has an article about it. Why would Wikipedia _not_ have any articles about foreign words?

Comment: By the way, for what it's worth, I just found out that the English Wikipedia has literally hundreds of articles about German words that are not used (or are only very rarely used) in English. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:German_words_and_phrases. About 90% of the words on that list are words I've never heard before.

Comment: compare with this list, which does not contain the word "heimat" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_German_expressions_in_English

Comment: @somebody CTLR-F'ing through that page does give me a hit for "urheimat" though, which is a derived word of heimat, albeit in a narrower context.

Comment: @Opifex *do* note that it is under the "linguistics" subsection of the "academia" section... which i'd hardly consider common use

Comment: @somebody I never said it was common use. On the contrary... I even said it probably wasn't very commonly used.

Comment: @Opifex do note by "i'd hardly consider common use" i mean: it's technical jargon so i'd consider it only slightly more legitimate than saying many latin words are in common use because species names are in latin. do also note that i believe the closest you went to saying "wasn't very commonly used" is either "don't know how common" or "in a narrower context"